# jQuery auto scroll to elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came across this useful blog [Smoothly scroll to an element without a jQuery plugin](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2)

In the below code

```
$('body#sliderOn').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Auto scrolls down to target-element if sliderOn id exists within the body, but, because i have a fixed navbar the target-element goes behind it and cause not to show 20px of the target-element on top. Any solution here?

Comment: Can you give an example? Maybe create a jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body#sliderOn').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top - 20
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Works Great :) Thank you.

Comment: seems like this does not work on firefox. Any solution?

Comment: Really? Strange... Are you getting any error message in the console? Or simply nothing is happening?

Comment: no, my bad, i used px right after the number xD what a noob

Comment: Haha, np, glad you were able to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help  :)